# Multiple function declaration inside "Base Query"after propel class rebuild

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, propel

I modified my db and some fk relations. After rebuilding schema and rebuilding classes I get an error message while trying to use the class

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare BaseHrlibQualificationLevelQuery::filterByHrlibQualification() in C:\wamp\www\cbm_hr\trunk\cbm\plugins\cbmHrLibPlugin\lib\model\om\BaseHrlibQualificationLevelQuery.php on line 717

I checked the schema but there are no multiple columns in the same table.

What other things can cause multiple declarations of the function?

Comment: `./symfony propel:build-all --classes-only`, `./symfony cc` and retry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just had a similar problem. Although your question doesn't mention if you have multiple Foreign Keys to the same foreign table but I suspect that is the problem.

I had:

```
<foreign-key foreignTable="dish" phpName="Dish" refPhpName="Menu">
  <reference local="soup_id" foreign="id"/>
</foreign-key>
<foreign-key foreignTable="dish" phpName="Dish" refPhpName="Menu">
  <reference local="main_id" foreign="id"/>
</foreign-key>
```

and I've got this error message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare BaseMenuQuery::filterByDish()

Then I've changed the phpName and refPhpName attributes (the later is needed because Propel will generate filterBySomething() function in the foreign table class so in my case there were multiple filterByMenu() function names):

```
<foreign-key foreignTable="dish" phpName="soupDish" refPhpName="sMenu">
  <reference local="soup_id" foreign="id"/>
</foreign-key>
<foreign-key foreignTable="dish" phpName="mainDish" refPhpName="mMenu">
  <reference local="main_id" foreign="id"/>
</foreign-key>
```

So I'm guessing that you have multiple references to HrlibQualification table by more than one foreign key.

I hope that helps.

Comment: this is a good start for an answer, but you havent really answered the OP's question. try to give more insight, or a proper solution.

Comment: The OP asked "What other things can cause multiple declarations of the function?" I think my answer gives at least one possible reason for it: multiple foreign keys to the same table. Unfortunately I don't know any other reasons because I've just started using Propel yesterday so I'm by far not an expert in it.

Comment: @Andrew I had isCrossRef: True set in _has_ table and yes I also had multiple references to HrlibQualification. It worked for me when I removed the isCrossRef. I haven't checked with different phpName and refPhpName but I think that will work too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am late on this but The solution of your problem lies in the structure of your table, you have two foreign keys pointing to the same reference, but one of them is not pointing to your table, that's why you see only one.

**solution**

execute the script

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name
```

to identify the duplicated foreign keys

then delete one usually the one that is not visible with the command

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP FOREIGN KEY `foreign_key_id`
```

then regenerate your schema with propel reverse

you should be good to go.